# Rails: Adding a "latest post" to blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails

---

### Adding a "latest post" section to blog

This is my original code to show **all** my posts and it works great.

```
<% @post.each do |post| %>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
    <a href="#portfolioModal6" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
      <div class="portfolio-caption">
        <h4><%= link_to post.title, post %></h4>
        <p class="text-muted"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %></p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

However, I also want to add a large div that shows my latest post. So I copy/paste the code above and changed the line `<% @post.each do |post| %>`to the following:

```
<% @post = Post.last do |post| %>
```

There was no errors, but nothing showed up either. The reason I added this code is because I saw in a tutorial where the teacher went into rails c and typed @post = Post.last and could see the last post created. However, when I go into terminal and type it, I get the error:

```
No command '@post' found, did you mean:
 Command 'mpost' from package 'texlive-binaries' (main)
 Command 'rpost' from package 'suck' (universe)
@post: command not found
```

Comment: A random guess, try <%=  instead of <%

Comment: @hook38 this would print the post. And you don't want something like `#<Post id: 123, title: "hi"...>` on your website right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending @oreoluwa's answer with a little more rails conventions:

Your post object:

```
class Post < ActiverRecord::Base
  scope :ordered, -> { order(created_at: :desc) } # or use your own column to order
end
```

Your Controller (where your view is where the last post should be rendered). You should not make queries in your views to keep better a better control.

```
class ExamplesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @latest_post = Post.ordered.first
  end

end
```

Your View

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
  <a href="#portfolioModal6" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
    <div class="portfolio-caption">
      <h4><%= link_to @latest_post.title, @latest_post %></h4>
      <p class="text-muted"><%= @latest_post.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %></p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I did everything right, I get the error: `undefined method title for nil:NilClass` `<h4><%= link_to @latest_post.title, @latest_post %></h4>`

Comment: You must add the controller code into the according action.

let's say your view code is in `app/views/examples/show.html.erb`, you need to place the code I posted (controller code) into the `ExamplesController#show` action. (which in fact is a function).
I updated the answer.
If it does not work, please share your code of your controller as well as the path of the view you posted.

Comment: IT WORKS!! I placed the controller code in the wrong controller.

Answer (score 3):

1. You shouldn't type it on your terminal, but in the rails console. On your terminal, type `rails console`, when that loads up, you can then do:

   ```
   post = Post.last
   ```
2. In order to only render for the last post, you wouldn't need the block, as such:

   ```
       <% post = Post.last %>
       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
         <a href="#portfolioModal6" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
           <div class="portfolio-caption">
             <h4><%= link_to post.title, post %></h4>
             <p class="text-muted"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %></p>
           </div>
         </a>
       </div>
   ```

By the way, it's not best practice to handle domain objects in your view. You could have this as an instance variable in your controller, as a Facade object if you have multiple objects.

Comment: It's not the best way to get the newest post using `.last` the sorting is always a bit different on different systems like an ubuntu or a os x.